# Flash actionscript 3 smoothly moving large sprites

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, move

I've got a problem in actionscript3 with moving large DisplayObject-s. When the size of the DisplayObject is quite large  (more than screen size) the movement loses smoothness and it looks like the object starts jumping forward and backward, which overall looks very unpleasant.

Does anybody know the way to fix that? I am trying to make a sort of a race game, where I need to move the background sprite to make the illusion of movement.

Comment: You will never get something smooth with a sprite larger than the screen (especially if the whole circuit is a giant sprite). It's better to split the background into tiles or some small elements, and move only what needs to be moved.

Comment: It's strange that graphics-optimized Flash fails in such a simple task. All it needs do is just to copy and paste a region from a bitmap. Do you know any way to optimize Flash, probably using a graphic card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to agree with Laurent - it is probably better to split the background into small pieces and move them

Answer (score 1):

Try turning on cacheAsBitmap. That may give you some performance improvements, especially if the object is static (doesn't have any animated bits in it). With AS3 and Flash Player 10 or newer you should be able to get smooth movement even with a large sprite. I've got several games that do it.

Comment: As far as I understand CacheAsBitmap caches your vector animation into bitmap in order to save math computation. But I am already moving a bitmap and I don't see how this can help. Any other ideas?